# Remote access in Apache Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I Have two machines installed apache cassandra, with IPs (192.168.1.101 and 192.168.1.102).

I want to remote login from 192.168.1.102 to 192.168.1.101

I edited rpc_address= 0.0.0.0 and cassandra.yaml file in 192.168.1.101

When iam trying to connect from 192.168.1.102 using

```
cqlsh 192.168.1.101 9061
```

iam getting error like this

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'192.168.1.107': 
error(111, "Tried connecting to [('192.168.1.107', 9160)]. Last error: 
Connection refused")})
```

Is there anything configuration i want to do in 192.168.1.102 or i missed anything.

Please help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see multiple issues here:

1. Cqlsh uses port 9042 to access cassandra, not 9061. It's declared in `cassandra.yaml` as `native_transport_port`
2. By default Cassandra listens for CQL connections only on `localhost`. See `listen_address` in `cassandra.yaml` and set it to node's public IP address.

I suggest:

- double-check cassandra logs that it completed the startup without errors.
- try to connect to localhost with cqlsh

Comment: Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserException: while parsing a block mapping; expected <block end>, but found BlockMappingStart;  in 'reader', line 450, column 2:
     broadcast_rpc_address: 1.2.3.4

Comment: Try not to mess with the default values in `cassandra.yaml` if you don't really need to change them. On cluster bootstrap, change only `cluster_name` and `seed_provider`.

Comment: Ok,. It was just a space in front of that line,. Thanq once again shutty

Comment: why do we use that broadcast_rpc_addresss???? Is there anything else to place instead of that 1.2.3.4??